# ESP8266 with Arduino Uno is not connecting and sending data to the Ubidots server

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, esp8266, at-command

ESP8266 with Arduino Uno is not connecting and sending data to the server Ubidots.

I need to send data to the server like Ubidots and I need your help. The below code, which I'm using and I'm not getting to post data and not able to connect to the server.

I'm using AT commands to connect to the server. My ESP8266 can connect to the WiFi and can send data to ThingSpeak server. As I need to add GPS to my project, so now I'm using Ubidots, but my problem is that I'm not able to connect and post data to the server.

```c++
#include <DHT.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>


LiquidCrystal lcd(13,12,11,10,9,8);

SoftwareSerial esp(2, 3);                   //RX,TX

#define DHTPIN 5                            // Digital Pin 5
#define DHTTYPE DHT11                       // We are Using DHT11
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);                   // Initialising Pin and Type of DHT

String ssid = "JioFi2_05";                           //wifi name  
String password = "80199102";                       //wifi password

String server = "things.ubidots.com";                         //ubidots server name

String token = "A1E-IcAmTnS42aTf79zQsmiNny";                          //ubidots token
String esp8266_d_id = "5a8adf76c03fee";                   //esp8266device id

String temperature_id = "5a8e9268c0ebcfede";                 //temperature variable id
String humidity_id = "5a8a73fb8083e6b";                    //humidity variable id
String heartbeat_id = "5a83f614e9049";                   //heartbeat variable id

void connectWifi()                           //wificonnection
{

  String cmd = "AT+CWJAP=\"" +ssid+"\",\"" + password + "\"";
  esp.println(cmd);
  delay(4000);

  if(esp.find("OK")){
    Serial.println("WIFI Connected!");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.println("WIFI Connected!");
    delay(1000);
  }
  else {
  connectWifi();
  Serial.println("Cannot connect to wifi");
  }
}

void reset() {

  esp.println("AT+RST");
  delay(1000);
  if(esp.find("OK") ) Serial.println("Module Reset");

}

void esp_buad_rate_change()
{
  esp.println("AT+CIOBAUD=9600");                  //change buad rate
  Serial.println("AT+CIOBAUD=9600");
}

void wifisetup()
{
  esp.println("AT");
  esp.println("AT+CWMODE=3");
  Serial.println("Wifi ready");

}
void ubi_send_data(String, String);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  esp.begin(115200);
  reset();
  esp_buad_rate_change();             //changing buad rate
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.println("Wifi Setup");
  wifisetup();                         //wifi setup
  connectWifi();
}


void loop() {

  float hum =  dht.readHumidity();             // Reading Humidity Value

  float tem = dht.readTemperature();        // Reading Temperature Value

  ubi_send_data(String(temperature_id), String(tem));
  ubi_send_data(String(humidity_id), String(hum));
  ubi_send_data(String(heartbeat_id), String(heart));


}

void  ubi_send_data(String id, String values){ 

 top:
 String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"" + server + "\",80";
  esp.println(cmd);
  delay(3000);

  if(esp.find("OK"))
  {
    Serial.println("server found");

  String cal="{\"value\": "+values+"}";
  int len =cal.length();
  String post = "POST /api/v1.6/variables/"+id+"/values HTTP/1.1\r\n";
         post+= "Content-Type: application/json\r\n";
         post+= "Content-Length: ";
         post+= String(len)+"\r\n";
         post+= "X-Auth-Token: "+token+"\r\n";
         post+= "Host: things.ubidots.com\r\n\r\n";
         post+= "{\"value\": "+values+"}\r\n\r\n";

  String sendData = "AT+CIPSEND="+post;
  esp.print(sendData);
  Serial.println(sendData);
  delay(6000);
    if (esp.find(">"))
    {
      Serial.println("SENDING  data"); 
    }
    else
    {
       Serial.println("NOT SENDING");
       esp.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("server not found");
    goto top;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not how you use `AT+CIPSEND` command

Comment: What's the server response? Or how does this code break?

Comment: I'm not able to connect to the server.

Comment: @gre_gor can you please tell me how to send AT+CIPSEND command

Answer (score 0):

May I ask you why you are using AT commands?

You could try to implement a simple Arduino/ESP8266 Ubidots HTTP client.